# Try Catch not working in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

```
try
{
    var orderedListOfRfidTags = uow.RfidTags.ToList().OrderBy(t => int.Parse(t.Number));
    return View(orderedListOfRfidTags);
}
catch
{
    var orderedListOfRfidTags = uow.RfidTags.OrderBy(t => t.Number).ToList();
    return View(orderedListOfRfidTags);
}
```

MVC3 - in Release mode this will still fail on the first line var ordreedListOfRfidTags...

I wonder why try catch isn't trying and catching?
[image]

then pressing F10 it goes to here.. which is part of my ORM wrapper... hmm I wonder if this is the problem.

```
protected override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            if (_unitOfWorkScope != null)
            {
                _unitOfWorkScope.Dispose();
            }

            base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure it's failing on the first line and not on the one in the catch? (e.g., uow.RfidTags is NULL)

Comment: Can you explain your code please?

Comment: What trying, what catching? Expected result? Actual result? What failing? If the first line fails what happens?

Comment: It can also be easy to forget that this will not catch any exceptions thrown while rendering the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that LightSpeed was failing out.  Once the support was added (very quickly - awesome product!) it all worked fine:

```
// trying to convert to an int.. if fail, use string
        // need up to date nightly build of LS3.1 for this to work
        // otherwise trycatch will fail due to LS crashing out.
        try
        {
            var orderedListOfRfidTags = uow.RfidTags
                                            .OrderBy(t => Convert.ToInt32(t.Number))
                                            .ToList();
            return View(orderedListOfRfidTags);
        }
        catch
        {
            var orderedListOfRfidTags = uow.RfidTags
                                            .OrderBy(t => t.Number)
                                            .ToList();
            return View(orderedListOfRfidTags);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The delegate passed to OrderBy is not invoked until you try to access the elements in the list.

So I think the error is not caught because your collection is not enumerated until the view is being rendered, after the action method has returned.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad design; you shouldn't have any code in your catch that could potentially throw another exception.

If I'm understanding your code, you want to attempt to parse the RFID to an `int`, but fall back on `string` as your sort if a failure?

If you can't gaurentee that the `Numbers` of the `RfidTag`s won't be a number (which seems a silly naming structure), then I'd leave it as a string sort and ditch the int parsing